# Is it possible to copy text from a field and print the text out into the line terminator?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a field (#2) which filled automatically after some text was put into another field (#1). I need to copy the text from the field (#2) which filled automatically to verify that texts in both fields are equal.

The Combination: FindElement by locator + using Text() doesn't work.

I can select text from field #2 and copy to buffer but no idea what to do next.

Appreciate your​ help!

Comment: Just store your data in string and compare it.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and your code trials

Answer (score 0):

Compare with the input text given for #1 if you are expecting it to be the same

"The Combination: FindElement by locator + using Text() doesn't work" : Please explain in brief about what happens. May be try with (.) instead of (Text())

Comment: This should be comment. If you don't have enough reputation then try answering the whole answer.

Comment: Using the next approach returns an empty string but text exists in the autocompleted field: string text = _webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("my xpath")).Text;